# query returns empty even though it should return a result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to query for the password of the person that matches the filled in username. This, however, is not working! For some reason the same query that works for one account doesn't work for another account. I have made sure that I didn't make any typo in the query or the username and I am sure that the username I searched for exists.

Example: 
**SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = 'admin'**
This gives me the password for the admin account.
**SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = 'user'**
This results in nothing, and there is no syntax error. I am certain there is a 'user' in my database.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the db-table?

Comment: Obviously there is none. Maybe there are whitespaces or something while inserting `user`, try LIKE search or trimming

Comment: There are no whitespaces. I used the exact same query I used on 'admin'. The only thing I changed was admin to user.

Comment: If the query of Hadi works, there must be some chars, spaces or soemthing unclean, try trim($var) before saving usernames

Comment: Despite using trim() I still have the same problem.          $passwordQuery = trim("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$checkPassword = mysql_query($passwordQuery);

$res = mysql_fetch_array($checkPassword) or die("Appointing result failed!");
print_r($res);
print_r is empty.

Comment: You have `trim()` in the wrong place. Should be `$passwordQuery = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE trim(username) = trim('$username')"; checkPassword = mysql_query(....`. You need to trim your column `username` and your value `$username`.

Comment: It would be good to also update all usernames and trim the spaces -> `UPDATE users SET username = trim(username)`. This would prevent this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the record that has username 'user' the value has space like this 'user ' or ' user'
so edit the record and make sure no space added, or you can do

```
 SELECT password FROM users WHERE username like '%user%'
```

to check if record is there.

or this

```
 SELECT password FROM users where trim(username)='user'
```

Comment: This query works. It gave me back the correct password, but will this method work when there are more users with a username that looks like user?

Comment: @user3546193: I recommend that you `SELECT HEX(username) FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%user%'` to understand what value `username` really contains, since it is not `'user'`.

Comment: This query returns: 2075736572. I am not sure what to do with it though.

Comment: so i am 100% sure that there is extra space

Comment: `0x2075736572` is the ASCII encoding of `' user'`.  As @Hadi.M has observed, that means that the `username` contains a (leading) space character.

Comment: This however is not what I typed. Here is a copy/paste of the query that results in nothing: SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = 'user'

Comment: @user3546193: Well, clearly, if `username` contains `' user'` then `username = 'user'` will be false.

Comment: try this "SELECT password  FROM users where trim(username)='user'"

Comment: Hadi the "SELECT password FROM users where trim(username)='user'" query gave the correct result! There is just one thing I don't understand, why do you need to trim(username) instead of trim(user)? I thought the 'user' contained the whitespace.

Comment: no the field in your DB contains the whitespace not the parameter that you give to where clause (:

Comment: @user3546193: Generally speaking, you won't want to do `... WHERE TRIM(username) = ...` as it is not sargable.  If the username is supposed to be `'user'`, it would be better to correct the data that is stored in the table; if the data in the table is correct, then it would be better to provide the correct string to the query.